# Sonicwall NSA 3600 - allow vlan access to one website

Tags: sonicwall

I have one physical interface (X0) on my sonicwall NSA 3600 with 4 different virtual interfaces (X0:V120, X0:V121, X0:V130, X0:V140) for the different SSID's broadcasted.

I Would like Vlan X0:v140 to only have access to a single website (pupil platform).

I've created an adress group which contains all the IP-adresses that server uses.

[image]

When I create an access rule to allow outgoing traffic or an access rule to block outgoing traffic there is no problem, all traffic passes or is blocked, but when I create an access rule to allow traffic to the specific ip-adresses of the pupils platform all traffic is blocked, even the website which shouldn't be.

[image]

Is it possible to help me out to overcome this problem?

Thanks a million!

Korneel Vanloocke

Comment: Are the pupil platforms accessing the sites using the IP address or are they using the DNS name of the website? Normally you would have to allow DNS and the web traffic for school web sites.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

Both the DNS name and the IP adress don't work. I've requested the IP adresses from the pupils platform servers to add to the adress group. Both options (DNS and IP) have been tested but do'nt seem to work.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Check the order of the access rules from LAN -> WAN. You may find the newly created rule has been automatically put underneath the debt all rule. If so you should be able to move this up the list so it is above the deny rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a [Packet Capture](https://support.sonicwall.com/kb/sw11163) filter and post the result in red (blocked packets) delivered to your public pupil platform!